# dpctl error connecting to switch

Tags: pox

I'm going through openflow tutorial
https://github.com/CPqD/ofsoftswitch13/wiki/OpenFlow-1.3-Tutorial
when I try to execute

```
$dpctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6634
```

or

```
$dpctl show tcp:127.0.0.1:6634
```

I'm always getting the same error

```
dpctl: Error connecting to switch show. (Address family not supported by protocol)
```

so can you please tell me why I'm getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake. I was creating the topology in Mininet specifying the controller as remote

```
sudo mn --mac --controller remote,ip=127.0.0.1
```

without running the controller on the machine first, so I just ran the controller first(NOX in my case)

```
cd nox/build/src
./nox_core -v -i ptcp:6633 switch
```

and that solved the problem.
thanks